# 365 API to run OneDrive on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, ms-office, preview, onedrive

(Asking here as per the instructions at http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/08/develop-using-onedrive-for-business-with-the-new-office-365-apis/)

I'm trying to run OneDrive on an Ubuntu machine.  Using https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d/ I'm asked to OAuth against the following URL:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?display=touch&client_id=000000004010C916&locale=en&scope=wl.skydrive+wl.skydrive_update+wl.offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf&response_type=code
```

However, because I'm using Office 365, my corporate account isn't recognised as a "live" account.

So, my question is two-fold.

1. Is there an OAuth URL for `login.microsoftonline.com/` (where I usually log in)?
2. If not, are there APIs which will allow me to pull a directory listing, upload files, etc?  Bonus - any Python libraries?

Answer (score -2):

All the details for how to call the REST API directly for OneDrive and OneDrive for Business are available on dev.onedrive.com. In particular, you can read more about auth here: [dev.onedrive.com/auth/readme.md](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/readme.md).

For OneDrive for Business, you can use this OAuth URL:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`

We also have a Python SDK available: https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-python.